# Remux to MKV but add all streams using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to automate FFmpeg to remux all video files in a given directory to MKV. I'm currently using

```
ffmpeg -i $INPUT -c copy $OUTPUT.mkv
```

However, some streams are skipped that way - for example, if there are 2 audio streams only 1 goes to the output file.

How do I specify that **all** streams from the input must be copied to the output?

Since I'm trying to automate FFmpeg, it would be best if the command does not change for each file, i.e. manually specifying all the streams with `-map` would require me to first parse every file. I would do this if I need to, but if there is a better solution I'd prefer that.

Comment: Per the agreement on [your own Meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168740/159624), this question should have gone to Super User. I voted to migrate.

Comment: From http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168743/170007 - *Developing applications using FFmpeg.exe and writing scripts to automate its usage → on-topic for both, but more on-topic for SU*. I'm trying to automate ffmpeg, so it's ontopic here, right? Oh, and thanks for the answer :)

Comment: As you like—I think it's borderline because there's not a programming language involved, and if it's `$INPUT` or `input.mp4` doesn't make a difference really. It's just that I've seen many of these questions closed here for the wrong reasons, so rather have them migrated before they end up being deleted at some point :) You're welcome.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> How do I specify that all streams from the input must be copied to the output?

The `-map` option can do this, with the shortcut `-map 0`.

For example:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c copy -map 0:0 -map 0:2 output.mkv
```

to copy the stream 0:0 and 0:2 to output.mkv.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c copy -map 0 output.mkv
```

to copy *all* input streams from input 0 (`input.mkv`) to the output (even if there are multiple video, audio or subtitle streams).

The `-map` value corresponds to the input number (`0` is the first input, `1` is the second input, etc): If you add an additional input (-> input 1), and also want to copy all of the contents, then you will need to add `-map 1`.

You can use `ffprobe` to analyse files and see which stream is mapped where. Try `-fflags +genpts` if you get an `unknown timestamp` error. For a detailed tutorial, see [the FFmpeg Wiki page on the `-map` option](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map).

Comment: And if you get the error `Can't write packet with unknown timestamp` you have to add `-fflags +genpts` after the ffmpeg command. See [this bug](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1979) and the workaround mentioned here http://askubuntu.com/a/413968/135671

Comment: In case anyone finds this answer but can't find `ffmpeg`; `ffmpeg` is no longer present in the Ubuntu 14.04 repositories, but its fork `avconv` does the same (`sudo apt-get install libav-tools`).

Comment: @JeroenHoek In addition, ffmpeg builds can be downloaded from http://ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: The wiki link now redirects here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map It is probably best to update it.

Comment: @Nulano Thanks. Next time you can just propose an edit to the post yourself!