# How To Transcode and Re-size A Video Without Compressing It In fluent-ffmpeg

Tags: javascript, node.js, compression, fluent-ffmpeg, transcode

Simple question, how can I transcode and resize a video in `fluent-ffmpeg`, without compressing it? I understand that [some transcoding processes may naturally affect file size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25573078/14849955), but is there a way to reduce or increase the `compression ratio` in `ffmpeg`?

I found other stack overflow answers for the `FFMPEG CLI` [CRF](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38380), but how can I adjust the `CRF` in `fluent`?

```js
//input {2160x1440} MOV 15MB

const command = ffmpeg()
        .input(video)
        .setFfmpegPath(ffmpegStatic)
        .setFfprobePath(ffprobeStatic.path)
        .videoCodec("libx264")
        .audioCodec("libmp3lame")
        .aspect("16:9")
        .outputFormat("mp4")
        .size(`1920x1080`)
        .save("./transcoded/wout/compression/video.mp4")
        
//output {1920x1080} MP4 15MB
```