# Edit MP4 Metadata with exiftool

Tags: exiftool

I have an MP4 file with `Title` metadata:

```
exiftool movie.mp4
```

Which gives:

```
Audio Bits Per Sample           : 16
Audio Sample Rate               : 48000
Handler Type                    : Metadata
Handler Vendor ID               : Apple
Title                           : Movie Title
```

I want to completely remove this `Title` metadata. I have tried overwriting the title:

```
exiftool -Title="" movie.mp4
exiftool -Title= movie.mp4
exiftool -Title="" -overwrite_original movie.mp4
```

The command takes awhile to execute, but exits with:

```
0 image files updated
1 image files unchanged
```

What am I doing incorrectly? How can I view what the `exiftool` error is? How can I remove the `Title` attribute? According to [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/exiftool), MP4 seems to be a supported file type.

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since the time of the original question, exiftool, as of ver 11.39, has gained the ability to create/edit a larger range of MP4/MOV metadata tags (see [Quicktime tags page](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/QuickTime.html)).  To remove the `Title` tag from a video the original commands that @James Taylor used will work:

```
exiftool -Title= movie.mp4
```

Or in batch with

```
exiftool -Title= /path/to/files/
```

These commands creates backup files.  Add [`-overwrite_original`](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#overwrite_original) to suppress the creation of backup files.  Add [`-r`](https://ExifTool.org/exiftool_pod.html#r-.--recurse) to recurse into subdirectories.

You can also use ffmpeg with a command similar to this, based upon [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049829/remux-to-mkv-but-add-all-streams-using-ffmpeg/15052662#15052662)

```
ffmpeg -i InputFile -c copy -metadata title= OutputFile
```

But as is, I believe this command will remove all metadata. I think that `-map_metadata 0` needs to be added to the command to keep the remaining metadata, but unsure of where.

Comment: Yep! `[QuickTime]     Title` So do you know of any alternative for editing this attribute? QuickTime does not have appear to have a CLI nor even a GUI option for this. Thanks again!

Comment: See edit on original answer.  I think `ffmpeg` can do it for you.

Comment: Awesome! This process seems to have worked. Thank you so much!